# How to access custom fields Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook has in their documentation an example for a custom sign-up form:

```
<fb:registration
        fields="[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'},
        {'name':'favorite_car','description':'What is your favorite car?',
        'type':'text'}]" redirect-uri="URL_TO_LOAD_AFTER_REGISTRATION">
</fb:registration>
```

I want to create something like this but instead of favorite car my custom field is the address and I want fb-only registrations:

```
       <fb:registration
        fields="[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'},
        {'name':'address','description':'Address',
        'type':'text'},{'name':'zipcode','description':'Zipcode',
        'type':'text'}]" redirect-uri="http://example.com/register-exec.php"\
       fb_only='true' fb_register='true'>
       </fb:registration>
```

After the user registers, does Facebook keep in their database the custom field address and zipcode?

I can run

```
$facebook->api('\me')
```

to get user info but can I do something like

```
$facebook->api('\me\zipcode')
```

I am making the website facebook-only so I want facebook to keep track of these fields (I don't want to make my own database for this). Also, how can I know if someone has registered to the website when they access a page of the site?

Thanks

Comment: "but can I do something like" --- you spent more time to ask, rather you would spent trying it

Comment: Why are you using FBML *and* graph api? It's a little bit backwards

Comment: @adlawson that's the XFBML needed to trigger the restration plugin - it's supported

Comment: @zerkms of course I tried it before asking, I am giving an example of what I want

Comment: @adlawson Whats wrong with FBML and graph api together? I want people to register (FBML) and then access data from Facebook such as their friend list (Graph Api) in the web site

Comment: @user If you're creating models to handle the graph API, why not use them for registration, rather than relying on facebook's javascript SDK to render your registration form. You should create your own forms, handle the data how you want and create a user yourself.

Comment: @adlawson but thats just more work and wouldn't look as good

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't keep any record of the values provided by the user to any custom fields the developer requests

Your own app needs to process and store those in your own database - they won't be retrievable via the API as they're only passed during validation and submission of the registration plugin

Comment: thanks Igy, does Facebook have an address field that I can use other than 'name' : 'location' which is just the city? I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation but Facebook does keep record of addresses

Comment: There was an address field launched briefly, but it was withdrawn shortly afterwards and there's no immediate plans to bring it back